# ¿Cómo puedo insertar strings a una array de strings en C++?

Tags: c++, array, string

estoy experimentando y me ha surgido la duda de cómo sería hacer una función que retornara un array de strings.

Para ello, tengo entendido que debo "declarar" la función como dirección de string (no sé muy bien que es lo que estoy haciendo realmente, soy ignorante, aunque tengo entendido que esto se debe a algo de las direcciones y el almacenamiento de los arrays).

Y entonces, debo declarar el array con el asterisco para indicar que es un puntero, y así poder retornarlo.

Luego, indicando el índice del array, le asigno valores.

```
string &strArrayFunc(int size) {
    string *strArray[size];
    strArray[0] = "First";
    strArray[1] = "Second";
    return *strArray[size];
};
```

Pero esto me da error al compilar:

```
error: cannot convert 'const char [6]' to 'std::string*' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*'} in assignment
strArray[0] = "First";
error: cannot convert 'const char [7]' to 'std::string*' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*'} in assignment
strArray[1] = "Second";
```

Mis dudas:

- ¿Por qué me da error al añadir strings? Veo que las strings que yo he puesto al compilador les consta como char, pero, ¿no sé supone que eso se adapta sólo? Si no, ¿cuál es la solución?
- ¿Es necesario hacer tanta redundancia para declarar y retornar la lista de strings? Tengo que poner dos veces el asterisco y el tamaño.
- ¿Por qué no tengo que devolver arrays a través de direcciones (o punteros, no cuál es el tipo de la función porque al principio declaro como dirección y luego como puntero)?
- ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un vector, una lista y un array?

Comment: Por favor, para próximas consultas, limítate a **1 pregunta cada vez**. Este es un sitio para responder preguntas técnicas **concretas**, no para publicar libros. ¿ Te has pasado por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) ? ¿ Y por el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) ? Ahí encontrarás información sobre como funciona el sitio.

Answer (score 4):

> ¿Por qué me da error al añadir strings?

Porque `strArray[0]` es un `std::string*`, es un puntero a la clase `std::string`, y le estás tratando de asignar un `const char*`(o `const char[x]`, ya que son literales). Esto funcionaría si `strArray` fuera un array de `string`, no de `string*`.

> las strings que yo he puesto al compilador les consta como char,
>   pero, ¿no sé supone que eso se adapta sólo?

Cuando tienes algo como la cadena `"First"`, eso para el compilador es un array de `char`s constante de tamaño 6, que consiste, en este ejemplo, de las 5 letras más un caracter extra para el caracter '\0', que en este tipo de cadenas indica el final de la cadena.

No se adapta, o sea, no hace la conversión automáticamente porque los elementos del array son punteros a `string`s, no `string`s como tal, los punteros sólo pueden almacenar direcciones de memoria.

Para que `strArray[0]` funcionara, tendrías que primero obtener el `string` a partir del `string*`(puntero), esto se hace poniendo el asterisco antes del puntero, por ejemplo, si tengo `int* px = new int(5)`, para obtener ese 5 tendría que escribir `*px`.
Entonces, si quieres asignar `"First"` a `strArray[0]`, tendrías que escribir `*strArray[0] = "First"`.

> ¿Es necesario hacer tanta redundancia para declarar y retornar la
>   lista de strings? Tengo que poner dos veces el asterisco y el tamaño.

No, y de hecho hay varios errores aquí. El primero, y es uno muy grave es que nunca debes regresar por referencia (la parte de `string&` del nombre de la función) algo que creaste dentro de la función.

Por qué? Porque cualquier variable creada dentro de la función, será destruida al terminar la función. Entonces este array llamado `strArray` al terminar `strArrayFunc()` ya no existirá, y si le regresas una referencia o un puntero a `strArray` al código que llamó la función, el array ya no existirá y todo puede pasar, puede terminar el programa por un error o puede haber corrupción de memoria, es lo que en C/C++ se llama "comportamiento indefinido".

Es importante aclarar que esto no aplica a regresar una referencia o puntero a alguna variable creada dinámicamente con `new`. Por ejemplo si `strArray` fuera declarado así: `string* strArray = new string[size]`. Aunque claro, el código que recibe este puntero de parte de la función tendría que borrar en algún momento esa memoria.

El otro problema está en el `return`. `strArray[size]` regresa sólo un elemento del array, recuerda que el operador `[]` accesa un elemento de un array o algún tipo de colección. entonces lo que estás haciendo en el `return` es tratar de tomar el `string*` que te regresa el `[]` y aplicarle el operador de "dereferenciar" o como se escriba en español, que es el que se usa para obtener el objeto apuntado por un puntero. Como el tipo de retorno de la función es `string&`, se regresa una referencia a este `string`, no a todo el array de `string*`.

También es un error regresar `strArray[size]`. Si `strArray` tiene `size` número de elementos, digamos que `size` es 3, y estos elementos van del 0 al 2(la primera posición de un array es 0), entonces sólo existe `strArray[0]`, `strArray[1]`, y `strArray[2]`. No existe un elemento `strArray[3]`, y eso es lo que se está tratando de accesar con `strArray[size]`. `size` siempre es la cantidad de elementos, no la posición del último elemento, la posición siempre es `size-1`.

> ¿Por qué no tengo que devolver arrays a través de direcciones (o
>   punteros, no cuál es el tipo de la función porque al principio declaro
>   como dirección y luego como puntero)?

No sé, hay casos en los que es conveniente hacerlo. Lo que no hay que hacer es regresar un puntero o referencia a un arreglo, o cualquier variable, creados dentro de la funcion de manera estática, sin `new`.

Y creo que confundes lo de dirección y puntero. Un ejemplo:

```
int x = 4;
int* px = &x;
int& refx = x;
```

La primera línea es una declaración de variable normal, y con una asignación también.
La segunda es un puntero que guarda la *dirección* de `x`, la dirección de `x` se obtiene poniendo un `&` antes del nombre de la variable.
La tercera línea es una referencia, esta se declara poniendo & después del tipo de variable y antes del nombre de la variable, esto cuando se está declarando. Algo que tienen las referencias es que es obligatorio inicializarlas en la misma línea en la que las declaras. Las referencias no son más que un alias, sólo otro nombre para la misma variable. La utilidad de esto es que puedes definir funciones que regresan referencias (como `strArrayFunc`, que regresa un `string&`, una referencia a `string`) de objetos o variables que seguirán existiendo aún después de que la función termine, puede ser una variable global, o tal vez alguna variable miembro de una clase.

La ventaja de esto es que al igual que con los punteros, evitas estar copiando objetos, arrays, etc, y así es más eficiente. La ventaja que tienen sobre los punteros es que puedes usar una sintaxis normal, como si fuera una variable cualquiera. Los punteros, para usar el valor al que apuntan, primero hay que aplicarles el `*`(como `*px = 8` para cambiar, no la dirección de `px`, sino el valor apuntado por `px`, ese valor, sería el valor contenido en la variable `x` en el ejemplo.

> ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un vector, una lista y un array?

`vector` es como un array, pero puede adaptarse y crecer si le sigues metiendo elementos aún después de crearlo. El array tiene un tamaño fijo. Los `vector`es almacenan su memoria de manera contigua, así que tienen varias ventajas de velocidad y eficiencia al accesar sus elementos.

`list` es un contenedor que almacena cada elemento en diferentes partes de la memoria de la computadora. La ventaja sobre `vector` es que para insertar elementos en medio de la colección es mucho más eficiente, si quieres hacer eso con un `vector`, el objeto tiene que recorrer todos los elementos que irán después del lugar donde vas a insertar el nuevo elemento, para hacerle espacio. Esto implica copiar uno por uno a su nuevo lugar. La desventaja de `list` es que no es tan eficiente accesar a los elementos, normalmente para acceder a un elemento en el medio de la colección o al ultimo, tienes que empezar desde el primer "nodo", que contiene un puntero al siguiente "nodo", y así hasta que encuentres el nodo que contiene el valor que estás buscando.